# googlle sheet script is very slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Please check my script.
we are 9 people using this sheet.
but script working very slow.
if is there any solution please edit my script and send it to me to avoid slower.

```
    function onOpen() {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      ui.createMenu('Automate')
        .addItem('Remove Protections', 'removeProtection')
        .addItem('Reset Calling Data', 'removeData')
        .addItem('Reset Master Data', 'clearContentsOnly')
        .addToUi();
    }
    
    var editorsList = ['mohammad.hossain2255@gmail.com', 'imran.ayub.khan1@gmail.com']
    function onEdit(e) {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      const dashboard = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dashboard")
      var sheetNames = dashboard.getRange("A2:A10").getValues()
      sheetNames = [].concat(...sheetNames);
      const index = sheetNames.indexOf(sheet.getName())
      if (index > -1 && e.range.getColumn() == 18) {
        var range = sheet.getRange('R' + e.range.getRow());
        var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
        var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
        protection.addEditor(me);
        protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
        protection.addEditors(editorsList)
        if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
          protection.setDomainEdit(false);
        }
        dashboard.getRange("M" + (index + 2)).setValue(new Date())
      }
    }
    
    function abdullahAssen(e) {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      if (sheet.getName != 'Abdullah Assen')
        return
      if (e.range.getRow() == 1 && e.range.getColumn() == 18) {
        // var range = sheet.getRange('R' + e.range.getRow());
        var protection = e.range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
        // var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
        // protection.addEditor('mohammad.hossain2255@gmail.com');
        protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
        protection.addEditors(editorsList)
        if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
          protection.setDomainEdit(false);
        }
        dashboard.getRange("M" + (index + 2)).setValue(new Date())
      }
    }
    
    function nasser(e) {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      if (sheet.getName != 'Nasser')
        return
      if (e.range.getRow() == 1 && e.range.getColumn() == 18) {
        // var range = sheet.getRange('R' + e.range.getRow());
        var protection = e.range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
        // var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
        // protection.addEditor('mohammad.hossain2255@gmail.com');
        protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
        protection.addEditors(editorsList)
        if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
          protection.setDomainEdit(false);
        }
        dashboard.getRange("M" + (index + 2)).setValue(new Date())
      }
    }
    
    function abdullahAssen(e) {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      if (sheet.getName != 'Abdullah Assen')
        return
      if (e.range.getRow() == 1 && e.range.getColumn() == 18) {
        // var range = sheet.getRange('R' + e.range.getRow());
        var protection = e.range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
        // var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
        // protection.addEditor('mohammad.hossain2255@gmail.com');
        protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
        protection.addEditors(editorsList)
        if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
          protection.setDomainEdit(false);
        }
        dashboard.getRange("M" + (index + 2)).setValue(new Date())
      }
    }
    
    function abdullahAssen(e) {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      if (sheet.getName != 'Abdullah Assen')
        return
      if (e.range.getRow() == 1 && e.range.getColumn() == 18) {
        // var range = sheet.getRange('R' + e.range.getRow());
        var protection = e.range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
        // var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
        // protection.addEditor('mohammad.hossain2255@gmail.com');
        protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
        protection.addEditors(editorsList)
        if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
          protection.setDomainEdit(false);
        }
        dashboard.getRange("M" + (index + 2)).setValue(new Date())
      }
    }
    
    function abdullahAssen(e) {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      if (sheet.getName != 'Abdullah Assen')
        return
      if (e.range.getRow() == 1 && e.range.getColumn() == 18) {
        // var range = sheet.getRange('R' + e.range.getRow());
        var protection = e.range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
        // var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
        // protection.addEditor('mohammad.hossain2255@gmail.com');
        protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
        protection.addEditors(editorsList)
        if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
          protection.setDomainEdit(false);
        }
        dashboard.getRange("M" + (index + 2)).setValue(new Date())
      }
    }
    
    function abdullahAssen(e) {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      if (sheet.getName != 'Abdullah Assen')
        return
      if (e.range.getRow() == 1 && e.range.getColumn() == 18) {
        // var range = sheet.getRange('R' + e.range.getRow());
        var protection = e.range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
        // var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
        // protection.addEditor('mohammad.hossain2255@gmail.com');
        protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
        protection.addEditors(editorsList)
        if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
          protection.setDomainEdit(false);
        }
        dashboard.getRange("M" + (index + 2)).setValue(new Date())
      }
    }
    
    function abdullahAssen(e) {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      if (sheet.getName != 'Abdullah Assen')
        return
      if (e.range.getRow() == 1 && e.range.getColumn() == 18) {
        // var range = sheet.getRange('R' + e.range.getRow());
        var protection = e.range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
        // var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
        // protection.addEditor('mohammad.hossain2255@gmail.com');
        protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
        protection.addEditors(editorsList)
        if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
          protection.setDomainEdit(false);
        }
        dashboard.getRange("M" + (index + 2)).setValue(new Date())
      }
    }
    
    function abdullahAssen(e) {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      if (sheet.getName != 'Abdullah Assen')
        return
      if (e.range.getRow() == 1 && e.range.getColumn() == 18) {
        // var range = sheet.getRange('R' + e.range.getRow());
        var protection = e.range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
        // var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
        // protection.addEditor('mohammad.hossain2255@gmail.com');
        protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
        protection.addEditors(editorsList)
        if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
          protection.setDomainEdit(false);
        }
        dashboard.getRange("M" + (index + 2)).setValue(new Date())
      }
    }
    
    
    
    function removeData() {
      var userMail = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()
      if (editorsList.indexOf(userMail) < 0) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You can't use this feature")
        return
      }
      var workBook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const dashboard = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dashboard")
      var sheetNames = dashboard.getRange("A2:A10").getValues()
      sheetNames = [].concat(...sheetNames);
      for (var s = 0; s < sheetNames.length; s++) {
    
        var sheet = workBook.getSheetByName(sheetNames[s])
        if (sheet) {
          sheet.getRange("R2:R").clearContent();
        }
      }
    }
    
    
    function clearContentsOnly() {
      var userMail = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()
      if (editorsList.indexOf(userMail) < 0) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You can't use this feature")
        return
      }
      var range = SpreadsheetApp
        .getActive()
        .getSheetByName("Master Sheet")
        .getRange("A2:Q");
      range.clearContent();
    }
    
    
    
    
    function removeProtection() {
      var userMail = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()
      if (editorsList.indexOf(userMail) < 0) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You can't use this feature")
        return
      }
      var workBook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const dashboard = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dashboard")
      var sheetNames = dashboard.getRange("A2:A10").getValues()
      sheetNames = [].concat(...sheetNames);
      for (var s = 0; s < sheetNames.length; s++) {
    
        var sheet = workBook.getSheetByName(sheetNames[s])
        if (sheet) {
          var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE)
          for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
            var protection = protections[i];
            if (protection.getRange().getColumn() == 18) {
              protection.remove()
              console.log(protection.getRange().getA1Notation())
            }
          }
        }
      }
    
    }
```

Please check my script.
we are 9 people using this sheet.
but script working very slow.
if is there any solution please edit my script and send it to me to avoid slower.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The code in the question has multiple function named `abdullahAssen` that doesn't make sense as functions names should be unique and also makes harder to review your code. Fix that and include a brief description of what the script should do and add more details about what you mean about being slow (you might include some execution logs as they show the execution duration).

Comment: All functions in a project must unique names

Comment: Hi cooper. may i have your WhatsApp number to to fix please. because i don't know anything about script. someone make it for me

Answer (score 0):

#### Make better use of the event object

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const names = dsh.getRange("A2:A10").getValues().flat();
  const idx = names.indexOf(sh.getName())
  if (~idx && e.range.columStart == 18) {
    const dsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Dashboard")
    let editorsList = ['mohammad.hossain2255@gmail.com', 'imran.ayub.khan1@gmail.com']
    let rg = sh.getRange('R' + e.range.rowStart);
    let protection = rg.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
    let me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
    protection.addEditor(me);
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    protection.addEditors(editorsList)
    if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
      protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
    dsh.getRange("M" + (idx + 2)).setValue(new Date())
  }
}
```

The chances are that with 9 users any onEdit function may be too slow for most users.  Generally you have to give onEdit time to operate and changing effectUser for each person is probably not going to work and I would consider using Lock Service as well, thus making it even slower.  Which boils down to saying this probably wont ever work fast enough for you.

Comment: Hi cooper. may i have your WhatsApp number to to fix please. because i don't know anything about script. someone make it for me. and i just coped your script. but it's not working.

Comment: What is the problem?